# using javascript to return a SHA-256 hash from a string

Tags: javascript, html, hash, sha

I'm very noob at javascript and HTML. Any help is appreciated.

This is a simple web page that is meant to return the SHA-256 has from a string input. The code has been ripped and simplified from here

https://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body 
<hr />
        <legend>String hash</legend>
        <form action="hash.htm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="theForm">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="text">Text:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="span12" name="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Hash" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-auto">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Results</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SHA-256</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I save this code as .html and open it with my browser, then try to return a hash, I am taken to a 404 not found page.

I'm sure it's something simple!! Thanks!

Comment: when you hit submit, the file will try to load hash.htm. I'm assuming your file is named something else.
I suggest you read a tutorial on how to build a simple form in PHP.
http://form.guide/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html

Basically your page is missing the code that actually does the hashing operation. Which could be php or other backend language which you can't see when you just grab the html from a page.

Comment: Thanks for your help!